Mockito Junit test case for while loop with break statement
I am writing Junit test case(Junit 5 with jupitar) for existing code that has while loop with break statement.
public int deleteRecords(int batchsize) {
   //some code here 
   int totalDeletedRecords = 0;
   while(true) {
       int deleted = deleteRecord();
       if (deleted == 0) { //means no record found to delete
          break;
       }
       totalDeletedRecords += deleted;
   }
}
private int deleteRecord()  {
    List<User> usersList = repository.findAll();  //get the records from the database; 
    if (CollectUtils.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    //then deleting the total records batch wise
    //construct list with ids and pass that to delete method
    repository.delete(List of ids);
    return userList.size();
}

My Junit test case,
@Test
public void testDeleteRecordSuccess() {
    //mock repository call
    User user = User.builder().name("xyz").build();
    when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(user));
    doNothing().when(repository).delete(anyList());
    int deleted = service.deleteRecords(1000);
    assertEquals(1, deleted);
}

As per the mock, always record has size of 1 and loop executes infinite. The loop needs to stop and also all lines of code should coverage.
Let me know how to mock the repository call in such scenario's.

Not sure what your real question is but there are so many problems with this code, int deleteRecords(int batchsize) - batchsize is never used.  What is CollectUtils.isEmpty() ? What is List of ids ?

@ScaryWombat I have not shared the complete code, just need to get how to mock the repository call in such scenario's ? like to break the while loop

don't know why closed the question, still waiting for the answer and searching in all resources.

Actually I got the solution like need to use thenreturn twice. first with parameter with data and second data with null or empty object - when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(user)).thenReturn(CollectionUtils.emptyList());

maybe you should let repository.findAll() return twice to test the loop.
@Test
public void testDeleteRecordSuccess() {
    // Create a test user
    User user = User.builder().name("xyz").build();
    
    // Create two lists, one with the user and one empty
    List<User> listWithUsers = Arrays.asList(user);
    List<User> emptyList = Collections.emptyList();
    
    // Mock repository calls
    // First call to findAll() will return the list with users, second call will return an empty list
    when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(listWithUsers, emptyList);
    
    // Mock the .delete() call to do nothing
    doNothing().when(repository).delete(anyList());

    // The service call should now proceed as expected, without any infinite loop
    int deleted = service.deleteRecords(1000);
    
    // Verify that records were 'deleted'
    assertEquals(1, deleted);
    
    // Verify calls to mock object
    verify(repository, times(2)).findAll();
    verify(repository, times(1)).delete(anyList());
}

